# Google Maps & jQuery implementation doesn't work in IE

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps-api-3

I added a google maps implementation based on google maps api v3 and this hiding/showing of results on this site.
The thing (whilst thoroughly ugly and surely not implemented well) works well in Firefox, Safari, and Opera, but doesn't work in IE. Well - it doesn't really work in IE <=7 at all and in IE8 it throws an error on this one:

```
($('.resultrow:not(:visible)').length == 0)
```

Could someone maybe take a look at this and give me any pointers on why this won't work?
You can get there from here: http://psych-info.de/index_distance.php
Just enter any German town's name in the first entry field ("ort:") and select any value (it'll be ignored anyways) from the "... km (Entfernung hier auswählen)"-dropdown.

Comment: try to be more strict with IE as in: $('div#id div.resultrow')